# Flutter Firebase: Map type vs sub-collection

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the structure below. A document in Firebase with the types Map, int and String. On the application screen, I have a specific widget to add a user and I have another widget to add the Address Map separately. So I thought of the following solution: I create an Address class with the attributes I need (city, street) and use those attributes to be able to save what the user types in the form of the screen. Then I do the conversion to map and save this information inside the user as an update.

Is this a good solution or is there a simpler way? Is it more interesting to have a sub-collection instead of a Map of address?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do what seems more "interesting".  Do what satisfies the needs of the queries you need to perform on this data.  This is the only real rule of data modeling for Firestore, because if you make a decision that doesn't work for the use cases you expect, then you will have a lot of work to do to change it.

I don't see anything here that needs a subcollection.

Comment: Thanks. I asked because i'm new into Flutter and a little bit insecure. But I liked your answer!

Comment: And what about a user with multiple addresses?

Comment: What about it?  What do you need to do in a query it that's the case?  You should catalog all of your requirements first, then model your data in such a way that those needs are met.

Answer (score 0):

Do what your application requires. If you feel your application will need a certain structure of data going forward then try to plan for this. But don't over-engineer too early in the development cycle.